# Unmarshal XML and store into Multimapping

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<input1>
  <concept name="Rad order">
    <input>varReasonForexam=Infection, post-operative;varReasonID=19666904</input>
  </concept>
  <concept name="Inpatient Encounter">
    <input>varFirstName=park123a;varLastName=sssrk123a;varSex=Male</input>
  </concept>
</input1>
```

This is my `Concept.java` class

```
public class Concept {
    private String input;
    private String name;
    public Concept() {} 

    public String getinput() {  
        return input;  
    }
    public void setinput(String input){  
        this.input = input;  
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getname() {  
        return name;  
    }
    public void setname(String name){  
        this.name = name;  
    }
}
```

This is my `Input1.java` class

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Input1 {    
    private List<Concept> concept;

    @XmlElement 
    public List<Concept> getconcept() {
        return concept;
    }
    public void setconcept(List<Concept> concept) {
        this.concept = concept;
    }
}
```

This is main class `RefactorClassArray1.java`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import java.util.Set;

public class RefactorClassArray1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> thisIsAStringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Multimap<String, String> strMapVariables = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Input1.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Input1 input = (Input1) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("varFile.xml"));

        List<Concept> list=input.getconcept();
        int isize = list.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < isize; i++) 
        {
            Concept concept = list.get(i);
            String strconname = concept.getname();
            String strinput= concept.getinput();
            String [] strarrinput = strinput.split(";");
            int arrsize = strarrinput.length ;
            String strinputval ;
            for (int j=0; j<arrsize; j++) {
                strinputval = strarrinput[j];
                strMapVariables.put(strconname, strinputval); 
            }
        }
        Set<String> keys = strMapVariables.keySet();
        for(String key: keys) {
            thisIsAStringArray.add(key);
        }
        System.out.println("thisIsAStringArray:" + thisIsAStringArray); 
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Output i am getting is

> strMapVariables:{Rad order=[varReasonForexam=Infection, post-operative, varReasonID=19666904], Inpatient Encounter=[varFirstName=park123a, varLastName=sssrk123a, varSex=Male]}
>   thisIsAStringArray:[Rad order, Inpatient Encounter]

My question is like this:
If i add one more input under `concept name="Rad order"` in XML,
This is my new xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<input1>
  <concept name="Rad order">
    <input>varReasonForexam=Infection, post-operative;varReasonID=19666904</input>
    <input>varReasonForpain=Ipain, pelvic;varID=19666905<input>
  </concept>
  <concept name="Inpatient Encounter">
    <input>varFirstName=park123a;varLastName=sssrk123a;varSex=Male</input>
  </concept>
</input1>
```

expected `strMapVariables` output like below:

> strMapVariables:{Rad order=[varReasonForexam=Infection, post-operative, varReasonID=19666904], Rad order=[varReasonForpain=Ipain, pelvic;varID=19666905] Inpatient Encounter=[varFirstName=park123a, varLastName=sssrk123a, varSex=Male]}

I want to use JAXB and mapping only, post code needs the output as collection of mapping. How to achieve  this?

Comment: Please anyone reply. Need it urgent

Comment: Your code (XML and Java) was hard to read and understand because of its poor formatting. People here are likely to spend some effort to help you,
only if they see some effort done on your side. Saying it is urgent for you, usually won't help. It would rather attract down-votes. Please read also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).